# Moving A Box into View Depending on Selection?

Tags: jquery

This is more of me asking for a solution instead of help with something I already have built.  I don't know if this effect has a name so I can only describe with examples..  I'm trying to create something similar to [this](http://woorktuts.110mb.com/art_of_reuse_code/index4.html#) but only displaying 1 box on the screen at a time and when the user clicks on a link it will slide a different box onto the screen replacing the first box.  Is there a name for this effect? Are there known scripts that do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a carousel.
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

If you are using bootstrap, the link above should be a simple way to implement it.

If you are looking for a stand-alone solution, try 
http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/.

A search would pop up more solutions.